# Extend a class with rectangle

Tags: android, rect

I want to extend a class called Square with Rectangle that is,

```
public class Square extends Rect {}
```

But the compiler complains as "The type Square cannot subclass the final class Rect"

Is there a work around?

Comment: i found similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114743/implement-a-subclass-square-that-extends-the-rectangle-class

Comment: You can not extend `final` classes and you can also represent `Square` using `Rect`...

Comment: It would be easy to get the source for `Rect`, use it as the template for a square, and modify the `intersects` methods etc.  Having said that, simply adding a check in your code that the two sides are equal when you set the xs and ys, you could use `Rect` as a square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A final class cannot be subclassed.

[Rect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html) is a final class. so cannot subclass the Rect class

Comment: I did not define any Rect class. Just imported: import android.graphics.Rect;

Comment: @Shibli it is a final class you cannot extends it

Answer (score 0):

Final Class cant be extended

i.e ex

```
public final class A {
}

public class B extends A {

}
```

gives compilation error

may be same whit your class Rect